# $2^{nd}$ order linear ODE, complementary function equal to driving force

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry, I am aware that the title doesn't make much sense; I am confused even on how to describe the problem. I am trying to solve the following ODE:
$$ \ddot{z}+9z=\sin(3t). $$
I get the complementary function:
$$z= A\cos{3t}+B\sin{3t}. $$
And to find the particular integral, because the driving force (is it called the source term?) is $\sin{3t}$ we take
$$ z = \alpha\sin{3t}+\beta\cos{3t} \\ \dot{z} = 3\alpha\sin{3t} - 3\beta\cos{3t} \\ \ddot{z} = -9\alpha\cos{3t}-9\beta\sin{3t}.$$
This implies
$$ -9\alpha\cos{3t}-9\beta\sin{3t} + 9(\alpha\sin{3t}+\beta\cos{3t}) = \sin{3t} \\ 0 = \sin{3t} $$
So my assumption that the particular integral is of the form $z = \alpha\sin{3t}+\beta\cos{3t}$ must be wrong, but I don't know what the right method is.

Comment: this happens because $\sin 3t$ is a solution of the homogenous equation; when that happens, try a combination of $t \sin 3t$ and $t \cos 3t$; a similar situation would occur with the first order equation $\dot z-3z=\exp 3t$

Answer (score 1):

This happens because $z=\sin 3t$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $\ddot z+9z=0$.

In that situation, try a combination of $t \sin 3t$ and $t \cos 3t$.

(A similar situation would occur with the first order equation $\dot z-3z=e^{3t}$.

The solution of that equation is $z=te^{3t}+Ce^{3t}$.)